# Distribute value across following NaNs using ffill in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, mean, fill

I have a dataframe of orders received such as:

```
 Date        Units
01-01-2020  2
02-01-2020  12
03-01-2020  NaN
04-01-2020  NaN
05-01-2020  5
06-01-2020  9
07-01-2020  NaN
08-01-2020  1
```

Sometimes customers will order higher numbers so they don't have to reorder the next 1 or 2 days. I am trying to find the average number the customers are using on any given day. For example, if a customer orders 12 and then does not order for 2 days, all three days' units should be changed to 4.
Output would be:

```
 Date        Units
01-01-2020  2
02-01-2020  4
03-01-2020  4
04-01-2020  4
05-01-2020  5
06-01-2020  4.5
07-01-2020  4.5
08-01-2020  1
```

I could do it with a combination of ffill and adding helper columns to count consecutive NaN values but I feel there must be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try use `isnull` with `cumsum` create the `groupby` key then do `transform`

```
df['Units'] = df['Units'].fillna(0).groupby(df['Units'].notnull().cumsum()).transform('mean')
0    2.0
1    4.0
2    4.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
5    4.5
6    4.5
7    1.0
```